# Is there a way for a Electron main process script to listen on messages posted by a page with `postMessage` function?

Tags: javascript, html, electron, w3c

I want to use the standard [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) API function in my page scripts that are loaded by an Electron renderer process.

I want to stick to Web APIs in renderer process scripts because the application is designed to run in both Electron and on the Web (in user's preferred Web browser). I don't want to tax source code readers with the likes of `if(typeof electron != "undefined") ...` or similar.

Is there a way to listen for messages that are generated by the `postMessage` function, or events dispatched by a script window, in an Electron main process script? That will allow me to maintain a graceful fallback in the renderer process script -- a posted message that isn't processed won't also generate runtime errors if not running in Electron.

So far I have been using the [`preload` property of the `webPreferences` object being passed to `BrowserWindow` constructor](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions) to load the following preload script which sets up a "communication bridge" I am after:

```
(() => {
    const electron = require("electron");
    addEventListener("message", ev => {
        switch(ev.data.type) {
            case "foobar":
                electron.ipcRenderer.send("foobar", ev.data.foobar); break;
        }
    });
})();
```

I can then do a `postMessage({ type: "foobar", foobar: { foo: 1, bar: true } }, "*")` as part of any renderer process script, and it will basically result in the renderer process sending the message to the main process, with the above set up by the preload script.

Ideally, though, if possible, I'd like to avoid having to use a preload script, but like I said I don't want to use any Electron APIs in renderer process scripts at all. If I could listen to messages posted by the renderer script "window" or to events dispatched by it, directly in the main process, that would eliminate my need for the preload script. But I don't know if it is possible, and reading the documentation gives me the impression I am going in circles or that I have exhausted my alternatives.

Comment: postMessage is in-process communication cannot pass across processes. You should use electron's built in ipc, or any other different mechanism can do interprocess communication.

Comment: There are already APIs which function across processes in Electron. There isn't anything inherent in `postMessage` that prohibits it to function across processes. In fact, I could override the function in a preload script if I wanted to, making it send a message to the main process *in addition to* posting the message to the window (using the original saved `postMessage` value) -- that would make it talk across processes. But I want to know if I have to do these things or whether Electron already exposes a mechanism like that, without me using Electron APIs in the renderer process.

Comment: yes, you are using those interprocess instead of postmessage by wrapping postmessage to call ipc internally. Electron `exposes` IPC, via electron's API - and electron never overrides plain renderer API for those purpose. To use electron's feature, you have to import it either in renderer process, or preload, or any other places.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but you can preload a script on the browser window that receives that message on the renderer process and copy that with `ipcRenderer.send` or `invoke`.

Comment: That's what I am doing already, as I outlined in the question.

Comment: my bad, I read that too quickly. but yes, that's the way to do it AFAIK